# How make distinct predictions for every observation using survreg for AFT models?

Tags: r, survival, cox-model

I have a life dataset where I have a few machines tested using the same parameter settings but results in different survival days. As an example below:

```
MachineID  Var1 Var2 Var3 Days_Survived Status    Prediction   
Machine 1  1,   1,   2,   150 days,     censored,  200 days
Machine 2  1,   1,   2,   100 days,     censored,  200 days
Machine 3  1,   1,   2,   210 days,     failed,    200 days
Machine 4  1,   3,   4,   430 days,     censored, 1000 days
Machine 5  1,   3,   4,   249 days,     failed,   1000 days
Machine 6  1,   3,   4,   440 days,     censored, 1000 days
```

I hope the table is clear. This is just an example to show what kind of predictions I am getting which is the same value for machines 1, 2, & 3, which all have the same parameter settings, and machines 4, 5, & 6, with another set of parameter settings.

How can I produce a prediction that is unique for each machine, instead of what I assume is the mean as produced by `survreg`?

Below is the code I have applied:

```
surv_func <- Surv(data$Days_Survived,data$Status)
weibull_model < survreg(surv_func~Var1+Var2+Var3, data=data, dist="weibull")

predictions = predict(object = weibull_model, newdata=data,se.fit=T, type="response")
```